# IBM Rhapsody Java API - Get every element in a project

Tags: java, rhapsody

I'm currently trying to find or make a function to get every item in a Rhapsody project, meaning the nested elements of the project and the nested elements of those elements, etc.

Is there an easy way to do this? And with easy I don't mean a looped function continually using the getNestedElements() function ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is method called **selected_el.getNestedElementsByMetaClass(ClassType, 0/1)** that will return all the elements of that MetaClass recursively based on 0/1 which is the second argument

ClassType is either Class, Port, Package -- find out the ClassType you are looking for

Alternatively there is **myPrj.findNestedElementRecursive( name, metaClass)** for example myPrj.findNestedElementRecursive( namedPkg, "Package") will find a Package under the 'myPrj' project that has a name that matches the value of the 'namedPkg' variable.

The Rhapsody Java API can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/introduction-ibm-rational-rhapsody-api).

Comment: Welp, bugger me. You're right, I thought that worked like getNestedElements() and only gets the element and its nested elements, but not the rest. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 2):

Try calling IRPModelElement.getNestedElementsRecursive on the project element:

[image: documentation for getNestedElementsRecursive]

Comment: Welp, bugger me. You're right, I thought that worked like getNestedElements() and only gets the element and its nested elements, but not the rest. Cheers mate!

Comment: Method 'getNestedElementsRecursive()' retrieves too much elements. It gets elements that we can't see in the Browser or Search window of IBM Rhapsody application too. I think that it can be system files. Is it possible to see only elements from the Model?